# Count the number of matched multiple pattern in R

Tags: r, regex, string

I have a vector of strings like this:

```
strings = c('abc||dhbsaf||fasdf||fasdf||dfs','abc||dhf||fa9df||fasaf||dfs')
```

And I have a pattern like this:

```
pattern = c('abc||dhbsaf||fasdf||fasdf||dfs','abc||dhf||fa9df||fasaf||32a')
```

And I want to count the number of matched patterns. For example, for the first pattern compared against the first string would give result of 5/5 and 4/5 for the next one. I am not sure how can this be done in R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could split the strings on `||`, and then do `%in%` on the corresponding elements of 'pattern' with that of 'strings'

```
colSums(mapply(`%in%`, strsplit(pattern, '[|]+'), strsplit(strings, '[|]+')))
#[1] 5 4
```

---

Or another option would be to extract the elements based on the 'pattern' and get the `lengths`

```
library(stringr)
lengths(str_extract_all(strings, gsub("\\|+", "|", pattern)))
#[1] 5 4
```